# On the scoring system for synchronised diving

Tags: olympics, scoring, diving

Whilst watching the current London Olympics I noticed that out of the 10 scores shown for each dive in synchronised diving, a few a crossed out each time.

Why are a few of the scores always crossed out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer: to prevent a judge from manipulating scores.

The highest and lowest scores are discarded (crossed out) and the middle scores are summed, weighted by 3/5, then multiplied by the degree of difficulty.

For London 2012, each overall score will be based on a middle score for each diver's execution and three middle scores for synchronization.

FINA defines the structure of scoring in diving [here](http://www.fina.org/H2O/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=904&Itemid=570).